# User/kernel memory split for Wine on Raspberry Pi 3B

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi3, wine

I saw a few post here and there talking about this issue, and the only two options seemed to be to either rebuild kernel with appropriate memory split or buy a package from [Eltechs](https://eltechs.com/product/exagear-desktop/).

Since were are talking about an open source software, I believe there should be people who got Wine (installed from [jessie-backports](https://wiki.debian.org/Wine)) working on RPi3 without buying some extra patch.

However, every time I build a kernel with required memory split option and try executing `winecfg`, it gives me this kind off error asking to build kernel with a different memory split option. So I'm going in circles here.

```
Warning: memory above 0x80000000 doesn't seem to be accessible.
Wine requires a 3G/1G user/kernel memory split to work properly.
wine: failed to map the shared user data: c0000018
```

So first it asked to rebuild the kernel with 2G/2G memory split, then, after I've done that, it asked me to build the kernel with 1G/3G, and then with 3G/1G again.

Can we, the open source people, sort this issue out once and forever and run x86 apps on RPi3? :)

Comment: I'm with the same problem. I tried using the image available in https://github.com/mikerr/RPi-QEMU-x86-wine but still getting that error.